# Clustering high-dimensional, categorical data

Tags: python, clustering, categorical-data, high-dimensional

I'm trying to cluster ingredients in recipes to see which recipes cluster together. This is a kaggle dataset here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shuyangli94/food-com-recipes-and-user-interactions with ~180k recipes (about 8000 ingredients). My idea was to explode ingredients and create a kind of one-hot vector and employ kmodes to look at how the different recipes cluster together. The issue is that even attempting on a subsection of 10000 observations (with clusters of 3-5) there is an enormous cluster of 0 and there is only one observation for 1,2,3,4,5. What are your suggestions for dealing with such high dimensional categorical data?

Original data (only care here about recipe_id, ingredient_ids and whether a certain ingredient is included in a recipe).
[image]

Data with tokenized ingredients (columns) and recipes (rows)
[image: 8]

Comment: Are all your variables (originally) nominal? How many such variables? How many different categories across all them? How many different categories approximately per each variable? Most valuable would be to show a snippet of your data right in the question body.

Comment: Sorry, I missed this comment...just added in snipped of data into question. If I fill the values with an empty string and code the "1" as a string as well, then that will do the trick for Kmodes...though on the full data, the kernel often dies.